# Facebook pixel breakdown by url has only has one url

Tags: facebook, analytics, facebook-pixel

I set up facebook pixel and I see the data and custom events works.
But if I want to breakdown event by url. I see only my domain link.
[Facebook pixel url breakdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxx76.png)

But I see in devtools that all facebook events are sent with corresponding url for the page
[Facebook devtools unique url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HunY6.png)

Does anyone know what to do in order I would see all URLs in the statistics not only domain URL?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.